# I am trying to create a database connector. The connector box is a Linux rhel511 on AWS. I am getting the error "unable to connect to the database"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a database connector. The connector box is a Linux rhel511 on AWS. I am getting the error "unable to connect to the database".

With the similar information i have already created a database connector for another connector box on our datacenter.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more information? Is your DB running on AWS? On an Instance? On RDS? What is your DB engine? Is you machine which is connecting to the DB on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm waiting for your further details, but as a first step:

- Check your DB Security-Groups
- If it looks fine, try to telnet the DB connection port from your instance. If telnet answers, it is not a SecurityGroup issue.
- Try to connect your DB from the DB instance (locally) (If it's running on an EC2 instance.)